# typescript: angular.d.ts defently typed with ng.IPromise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, typescript1.5

I'm getting this ts error while I'm trying to chain ng.IPromise function calls:

```
Error:(101, 23) TS2345: Argument of type 'IPromise<IResult[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IResult[]'. Property 'length' is missing in type 'IPromise<IResult[]>'.
```

Code:

```js
public search(stateParams : any, page : any) : ng.IPromise<Array<app.search.entities.IResult>> {

 // create promise
 let deferred : ng.IDeferred<Array<app.search.entities.IResult>> = this.$q.defer();

 // ensure page is a number
 page = (isNaN(page)) ? 1 : parseInt(page, 10);

 // create query
 this.searchServiceSearchQuery.getQuery(
  stateParams,
  this._itemsPerPage,
  (page * this._itemsPerPage) - this._itemsPerPage,
  null
 ).then(
  (query : any) : void => {

   // search
   deferred.resolve(this._search(query)); // <= THIS "this" THROWS THE ERROR ABOVE

  }
 );

 // return promise
 return deferred.promise;

}


private _search(query : any) : ng.IPromise<Array<app.search.entities.IResult>> {

// create deferred
let deferred : ng.IDeferred<Array<app.search.entities.IResult>> = this.$q.defer();

// run query
this.coreServiceRestangularHelpmeSearch
 .one('search')
 .get({q : query})
 .then(
  (data : any) : void => {

   // found results
   if (
    data !== null &&
    'results' in data === true
   ) {

    // create entities
    let entities : Array<app.search.entities.IResult> = [];

    // walk through all results
    data.results.forEach((result : any) : void => {

     // create entity
     let entity : app.search.entities.IResult = new app.search.entities.Result(
      result.id,
      result.cat1Ids[0],
      result.cat2Ids[0],
      result.cat3Ids[0],
      result.typeCode,
      (result.sort)    ? parseInt(result.sort, 10) : null,
      result.title,
      result.description,
      this.$sce.trustAsHtml(result.summary),
      false
     );

     entities.push(entity);

    });

    // sort all by sort key
    entities.sort(
     (
      a : app.search.entities.IResult,
      b : app.search.entities.IResult
     ) : number => {

      if (a.getSortKey() > b.getSortKey()) {

       return 1;

      } else if (a.getSortKey() < b.getSortKey()) {

       return -1;

      }

      return 1;

     }

    );

    deferred.resolve(this._extendResults(entities));

   }

   // return empty object
   deferred.reject('invalid api response');

  },
  () : any =>  {

   deferred.reject('failed to fetch search results');

  }

 )

;
```

Do I do something wrong or is there an issue with the def-typed file? If I change the generic of the `_search()` function to `any`, everything looks fine.

Comment: Your example is long and there is a blank line on line 101 of your sample. I guess that's why nobody had a look into your issue. Just mark where the error occurs in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Inside resolve method you should pass variable of type:

```
Array<app.search.entities.IResult>
```

not of type:

```
ng.IPromise<Array<app.search.entities.IResult>>.
```

Your code will be correct if you write something like this:

```
this._search(query).then((data)=>{
     deferred.resolve(data);
});
```

instead of

```
deferred.resolve(this._search(query));
```

It will be compiled, but I don't know your code logic, tune it itself.